# TradingView Pine Script - Is there any way to create an alert in this script?

Tags: pine-script, alert

I want a simple alert that triggers when the indicator changes from red to green or green to red (the last 2 dots are different colors), but because it uses *`line.new`* I can't figure out how can I do it.

This indicator is "Fourier Extrapolator of Price" by Loxx

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2. at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2./
// © loxx


//@version=5
indicator("Fourier Extrapolator of Price [Loxx]", shorttitle = "FEP [Loxx]", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)

greencolor = #2DD204
redcolor = #D2042D 

src = input.source(open, "Source")
npast = input.int(400, "Past Bars", maxval = 500)
nharm = input.int(20, "Harmonic Period", minval = 1)
frqtol = input.float(0.0001, "Frequency Tolerance")

x = array.new<float>(npast, 0.)
xm = array.new<float>(npast, 0.)

if barstate.islast
    av = 0.
    for i = 0 to npast - 1 
        array.set(x, i, nz(src[i])) 
        av += array.get(x, i)
    av /= npast
    
    //--- initialize model outputs

    for i = 0 to npast - 1
        array.set(xm, i, av)

    beta = 0.
    alpha = 0.
    w = 0., m= 0., a= 0., b= 0.
    z = array.new<float>(npast, 0.)
    
    //--- fit trigonometric model and calculate predictions
    for harm = 1 to nharm
        //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
        //| Quinn and Fernandes algorithm for finding frequency              |
        //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
        alpha := 0.
        beta := 2.
        array.set(z, 0, array.get(x, 0) - array.get(xm, 0))
        while math.abs(alpha - beta) > frqtol  
            alpha := beta
            array.set(z, 1, array.get(x, 1) - array.get(xm, 1) + alpha * array.get(z, 0))
            num = array.get(z, 0) * array.get(z, 1)
            den = array.get(z, 0) * array.get(z, 0)
            for i = 2 to npast - 1
                array.set(z, i, array.get(x, i) - array.get(xm, i) + alpha * array.get(z, i - 1) - array.get(z, i - 2))
                num += array.get(z, i - 1) * (array.get(z, i) + array.get(z, i - 2))
                den += array.get(z, i - 1) * array.get(z, i - 1)
            beta := num / den
        w := math.acos(beta / 2.)
    
        //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
        //| Least-squares fitting of trigonometric series                    |
        //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
        Sc = 0.,  Ss = 0., Scc = 0.
        Sss = 0., Scs = 0., Sx = 0.
        Sxc = 0., Sxs = 0., den = 0.
        n = npast
        for i = 0 to npast - 1
            c = math.cos(w * i)
            s = math.sin(w * i)
            dx = array.get(x, i) - array.get(xm, i)
            Sc += c
            Ss += s
            Scc += c * c
            Sss += s * s
            Sx += dx
            Sxc += dx * c
            Sxs += dx * s
        Sc /= n
        Ss /= n
        Scc /= n
        Sss /= n
        Scs /= n
        Sx /= n
        Sxc /= n
        Sxs /= n
        if (w == 0.) 
            m := Sx
            a := 0.
            b := 0.
        else 
            den := math.pow(Scs - Sc * Ss, 2) - (Scc - Sc * Sc) * (Sss - Ss * Ss)
            a := ((Sxs - Sx * Ss) * (Scs - Sc * Ss) - (Sxc - Sx * Sc) * (Sss - Ss * Ss)) / den
            b := ((Sxc - Sx * Sc) * (Scs - Sc * Ss) - (Sxs - Sx * Ss) * (Scc - Sc * Sc)) / den
            m := Sx - a * Sc - b * Ss
        
        for i = 0 to  npast - 1
            array.set(xm, i, array.get(xm, i) + m + a * math.cos(w * i) + b * math.sin(w * i))

    for i = 0 to array.size(xm) - 1
        colorout = i < array.size(xm)-2 ? array.get(xm, i) > array.get(xm, i + 1) ? greencolor : redcolor : na
        line1 = line.new(bar_index - i + 1, array.get(xm, i), bar_index - i, array.get(xm, i), width=6, color=colorout, style=line.style_solid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alert() function

```
for i = 0 to array.size(xm) - 1
    colorout = i < array.size(xm)-2 ? array.get(xm, i) > array.get(xm, i + 1) ? greencolor : redcolor : na
    if colorout == greencolor and colorout[1] == redcolor
        alert("Red to Green", alert.once_per_bar_close)
    else if colorout == redcolor and colorout[1] == greencolor
        alert("Green to Red", alert.once_per_bar_close)
```